# Pyqtgraph multiple grids shown with multiple axis

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

When I create a plot with an additional top and right axis, two additional grid lines are shown for these axis. The graph looks a mess with four sets of grid lines. How can I only display the gridlines for the top and right axis? The ticks and labels for the bottom and left should line up with the ticks of the top and right, i.e. be based off the top and right tick. Using the function setGrid() for the bottom and left axis doesn't work.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import sys

class CustomAxis(pg.AxisItem):

    def __init__(self, scale, label=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setLabel(label)
        self.scale = scale

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        ret = list()
        for v in values:
            if v > 0:
                ret.append('{:.2f}%'.format(v*scale))
            else:
                ret.append('')
        return ret
    

def create_plot(pw):
    p1 = pw.plotItem
    p1.setLabels(left='axis 1')

    #Doesn't work
    p1.getAxis('bottom').setGrid(False)
    p1.getAxis('left').setGrid(False)

    #Custom top axis
    p1.layout.removeItem(p1.getAxis('top'))
    caxis = CustomAxis(0.95, 'Percent Value', orientation='top', parent=p1)
    caxis.linkToView(p1.vb)
    p1.axes['top']['item'] = caxis
    p1.setAxisItems(axisItems = {'top': caxis})

    #Custom right axis
    p1.layout.removeItem(p1.getAxis('right'))
    raxis = CustomAxis(0.33, 'Saturation', orientation='right', parent=p1)
    raxis.linkToView(p1.vb)
    p1.axes['right']['item'] = raxis
    p1.setAxisItems(axisItems = {'right': raxis})

    x = np.arange(1, 7)
    y = x**2
    p1.plot(x,y)
    p1.showGrid(True, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.mkQApp()
    pw = pg.PlotWidget()
    pw.show()
    pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultipleXAxes')
    create_plot(pw)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```